# Laravel controller not adding all of the data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

My controller receives values from a form and sends it to the database. the validator works, which means I am indeed received all the necessary inputs from the form, including username.

However, when I look at my database directly, all fields are full but the username field, which is consistently blank... Any thoughts?

```
    public function postCreate(){

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'email'          => 'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
    'username'       => 'required|max:40|min:3|unique:users',
    'password'   => 'required|min:6',
    'password_again' => 'required|same:password',
    'carehome_type'  => 'required',
    'carehome_name'  => 'required'
                    ));

    if ($validator->fails()) {return Redirect::route('account-create')
        ->witherrors($validator)
        ->withinput();
            } else {

                //Assign form data to variables
                $email          = Input::get('email');
                $username       = Input::get('username');
                $password       = Input::get('password');
                $carehome_name      = Input::get('carehome_name');
                $carehome_type      = Input::get('carehome_type');

                //Activation Code generated here
                $code               = str_random('60');

                //Create user in database
                $user = User::create(array(
                    'email'         => $email,
                    'username'      => $username,
                    'password'      => Hash::make($password),
                    'code'          => $code,
                    'active'        => 0,
                    'carehome_name'         => $carehome_name,
                    'carehome_type'         => $carehome_type
                ));
```

Comment: Err..do you have a field 'username' in your form? Sometimes it's these silly mistakes that drive us crazy

Comment: How are your guard and fillable arrays set in your model?

Comment: The method create() in laravel uses guard and fillable, so if you don't tell laravel to store username, it won't.

Comment: @DamienPirsy yes there is a field username

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro you were right actually!!!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "assigning form data to variables" which just consumes memory pointless, you could build the array directly, something like this:

```
$userArray = array(
    'email'         => Input::get('email'),
    'username'      => Input::get('username'),
    'password'      => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
    'code'          => $code,
    'active'        => 0,
    'carehome_name'         => Input::get('carehome_name'),
    'carehome_type'         => Input::get('carehome_type')
);
```

Then just create the user

```
$user = User::create($userArray);
```

As for your problem, please do the following:

1. Check for typos in your code
2. Check your model if you have protected username for mass assignment. If you don't know what that is, here are the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your user this way and see if you still have problems:

```
// Create a user model
$user = new User;

// Assign form data to variables
$user->email          = Input::get('email');
$user->username       = Input::get('username');
$user->password       = Input::get('password');
$user->carehome_name  = Input::get('carehome_name');
$user->carehome_type  = Input::get('carehome_type');

// Activation Code generated here
$user->code           = str_random('60');

// Create the user in database
$user->save();
```